# Getting values from an array and checking (ticking) related checkboxes

Tags: javascript, html, forms, checkbox

I need your help.

How can I get the value(s) from an array and check (tick) their related checkboxes using HTML 5's data attribute?

Ie.

```
var x = "[monday,thursday]"

<input name="recurr_weekday" type="checkbox" data-weekday="sunday">
<input name="recurr_weekday" type="checkbox" data-weekday="monday">
<input name="recurr_weekday" type="checkbox" data-weekday="tuesday">
<input name="recurr_weekday" type="checkbox" data-weekday="wednesday">
<input name="recurr_weekday" type="checkbox" data-weekday="thursday">
<input name="recurr_weekday" type="checkbox" data-weekday="friday">
<input name="recurr_weekday" type="checkbox" data-weekday="saturday">
```

...after some processing the following checkboxes would have a tick in them:

```
<input name="recurr_weekday" type="checkbox" data-weekday="monday">
<input name="recurr_weekday" type="checkbox" data-weekday="thursday">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's another solution with a few advantages:

- It works even if there are multiple checkboxes for the same day, e.g., two checkboxes with `data-weekday="monday"`.
- It un-checks any `recurr_weekday` checkboxes that are **not** in your array of selected days.
- It only queries the document once, which is more efficient - especially if the document is large.

```js
document.querySelector('button').onclick = checkTheDays;

var myDays = ["monday", "thursday"];

function checkTheDays() {
  var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('[name="recurr_weekday"]');

  for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
    checkboxes[i].checked = myDays.indexOf(checkboxes[i].getAttribute('data-weekday')) > -1;
  }
}
```

```html
Week 1:
<input name="recurr_weekday" type="checkbox" data-weekday="sunday">
<input name="recurr_weekday" type="checkbox" data-weekday="monday">
<input name="recurr_weekday" type="checkbox" data-weekday="tuesday">
<input name="recurr_weekday" type="checkbox" data-weekday="wednesday">
<input name="recurr_weekday" type="checkbox" data-weekday="thursday">
<input name="recurr_weekday" type="checkbox" data-weekday="friday">
<input name="recurr_weekday" type="checkbox" data-weekday="saturday">(Initially all unchecked)
<br />Week 2:
<input name="recurr_weekday" type="checkbox" data-weekday="sunday" checked>
<input name="recurr_weekday" type="checkbox" data-weekday="monday" checked>
<input name="recurr_weekday" type="checkbox" data-weekday="tuesday" checked>
<input name="recurr_weekday" type="checkbox" data-weekday="wednesday" checked>
<input name="recurr_weekday" type="checkbox" data-weekday="thursday" checked>
<input name="recurr_weekday" type="checkbox" data-weekday="friday" checked>
<input name="recurr_weekday" type="checkbox" data-weekday="saturday" checked>(Initially all checked)
<br />
<button>
  Check Mondays and Thursdays
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use attribute selector

```
var x = ["monday", "thursday"];

for (let prop of x) {
  document.querySelector("input[type=checkbox][data-weekday=" + prop + "]")
  .checked = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the code below:

```
x.forEach(function (weekDay){
    var htmlElement = document.querySelectorAll('[data-weekday="'+weekDay+'"]').checked = true;
});
```

it will iterate trhough the array x, and each value we will find the corresponding element with the data-weekday value property.